# Angular universal route on server side

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-universal

Is it possible to route only on server side, so that the client already will receive the redirected route?

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    // Only do this once when rendered by server
    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
      this.router.navigate([`/`]);
    }
}
```

This code doesn't seem to have any effect. It will only navigate when I remove the isPlatformServer condition. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: I believe the SSR is only run once, on the first request. Once user is on a page, if he goes to an other page, server is not requested again. Did you try making a CanActivateGuard with this same code ?

Comment: But this code is on the page that is requested first. I can also see that this code is executed when I add logs, but the navigate simply has no effect.

Comment: do you see log on the nodejs side ? Please give a try to the CanActivateGuard either way. You can also move this code to the constructor instead of the ngOnInit.

Comment: Yes I see the log in nodejs. I think it doesn't work since the client requests a specific url, and the server cannot return a different url unless it was somekind of a Redirect (Status 302) response. So I guess routing on server side only is not possible.

Comment: indeed, the routing process may be strange. user is requesting `/foo`, he may receive the content of `/bar`, but client's url is still `/foo`. So when the client receives `/bar` HTML code, he then runs its own Angular which resolves the `/foo` route, and say "wait, the HTML I received is not right, I update it to the actual route `/foo`". Can you check what does the client receives, to see if the HTML receive is the one of `/foo` or `/bar` ?

Comment: Redirect is something that your backend framework should be doing

Answer (score 1):

Use response.redirect(status_code, URL) in your server-side code.
U can inject a RESPONSE object in your component or service to call response. redirect method, also don't forget the 301(or other) status code otherwise google will see 2 same pages with different URLs and the same content.

```
constructor(@Optional() @Inject(RESPONSE) private response: any,
            @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId: any) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
      this.response.redirect(301, '/');
    }
}
```